# Removing altered stopwords

Tags: python-3.x, set, nltk, list-comprehension, stop-words

**Background:**

1) I have the following code to remove `stopwords` using the nltk package:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

your_string = "The dog does not bark at the tree when it sees a squirrel"
tokens = word_tokenize(your_string)
lower_tokens = [t.lower() for t in tokens]
filtered_words = [word for word in lower_tokens if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

2) This code works to remove `stopwords` such as `the` as seen here:

```
['dog', 'barks', 'tree', 'sees', 'squirrel']
```

3) I altered the `stopwords` to keep the word `not` with the following code:

```
to_remove = ['not']
new_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english')).difference(to_remove)
```

**Problem:**

4) But when I use `new_stopwords` with the following code:

```
your_string = "The dog does not bark at the tree when it sees a squirrel"
tokens = word_tokenize(your_string)
lower_tokens = [t.lower() for t in tokens]
filtered_words = [word for word in lower_tokens if word not in new_stopwords.words('english')]
```

5) I get the following error because `new_stopwords` is a `set`:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'words'
```

**Question:**

6) How do I use the newly defined `new_stopwords` to get the desired output:

```
['dog', 'not','barks', 'tree', 'sees', 'squirrel']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but your read of the error message is faulty: The problem isn't that "`new_stopwords` is a `set`", as you say, but that a "`set` doesn't have the attribute `words`"

Which, it doesn't. `new_stopwords` is a set, which means you can use it directly in the list comprehension:

```
filtered_words = [word for word in lower_tokens if word not in new_stopwords]
```

You could also save yourself the trouble of making a modified list of stop words and just use two conditions:

```
keep_list = ['not']
filtered_words = [word for word in lower_tokens if (word not in stopwords.words("english")) or (word in keep_list)]
```